# MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID Returns 0 in Stored Procedure but not Manually Executed

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE 2: If I manually replace the EXECUTE code sample below with the actual SQL code to be executed, it works perfectly fine, which tells me the issue is tired to PREPARE, EXECUTE and DEALLOCATE PREPARE.**

**UPDATE 1: Actually, it appears every single stored procedure has stopped working (e.g. 0 always returned on insert). What's very strange is when I MANUALLY execute the insert, I get the index back just fine. But when it's executed via Stored Procedure, it's always 0. The only thing that's changed is I rebooted my system. That's it. Note this is my local 127.0.0.1 MySQL installation. Any reason why a manual execute of INSERT would return a LAST_INSERT_ID() but a stored procedure of the exact same insert would fail? I am not using commit/rollback in the SPs and haven't changed the default system setting for commits**

This is quite the head scratcher. I have a large and complex Stored Procedure that builds a SQL INSERT from dynamic JSON field data. It was working perfectly until I merged multiple updates into a single SP to support transaction rollback (but I haven't put any of that code in yet).

The code executing the SQL select statement is:

```
SET @mysql := var_sql_insert;
PREPARE SQLStatement1 FROM @mysql;
EXECUTE SQLStatement1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE SQLStatement1;
SET var_company_main_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Below is the SQL code that's being executed:

```
INSERT INTO company_main  (company_owner_account_ref_id,company_name,company_industry_ref_id,company_size_c,company_type_c,company_date_founded) VALUES (1,'TestCompany',2,1,1,'2009/05/06')
```

The issue is LAST_INSERT_ID() is returning 0 each and every time I execute the SQL statement in the stored procedure, but if I manually execute it, the LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the index just fine. Note the table I'm doing the INSERT to has a properly defined PK Auto-Increment Index, so that's not the issue (which seems to be the #1 cause of the 0 result).

What's even more nuts is this exact same code worked perfectly fine before - it hasn't changed - the only thing I did was put it in a larger stored procedure and add a Label to the BEGIN (because I execute LEAVE on error).

When I walk the code, it executes perfectly; it's just LAST_INSERT_ID() always returns 0 now even when the record is inserted just fine (along with the incremented ID/index).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which will not give you the generated id as expected.

Comment: Actually, it appears every single stored procedure has stopped working (e.g. 0 always returned on insert). What's very strange is when I MANUALLY execute the insert, I get the index back just fine. But when it's executed via Stored Procedure, it's always 0. The only thing that's changed is I rebooted my system. That's it. Note this is my local 127.0.0.1 MySQL installation. Any reason why a manual execute of INSERT would return a LAST_INSERT_ID() but a stored procedure of the exact same insert would fail?

Comment: Sounds like a session scope issue. Why not simply return the LAST_INSERT_ID() from your stored procedure as an OUT parameter ?

Comment: I do. And it's worked for weeks. The issue is it's always returning 0 now in any stored procedure regardless of the Insert. Same code that's worked for weeks - only difference (as I mentioned) is I rebooted my system. Is there any reason LAST_INSERT_ID() would always return 0 in a SP but works with a manual execution while not using transactions in the SPs? It's as if rebooting turned something off.

Comment: @Floobinator Please [edit] your question to include the table structures and the stored procedures you have as a [mcve] to your question. Also add the statements on how you call the stored procedures and how you read the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` value. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: As I said, any and every INSERT fails with this error, regardless of table, even as simple as INSERT INTO Table (Col1) VALUES ('Yay'); and as mentioned they work perfectly fine if executed manually outside of the SP. This is some sort of system/setting issue, not a problem with the INSERT statements (all which worked just fine until the system reboot). I'm thinking there may be some system global setting or variable causing this problem; somehow marking the Stored Procedures as something different than they were before...

Comment: Note I've updated the main post - it appears the issues revolve around PREPARE, EXECUTE and DEALLOCATE PREPARE as replacing EXECUTE XXX with the exact same statement (from XXX) works perfectly fine. Even stranger, even though LAST_INSERT_ID returns 0 the record is created. Each time.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems this issue is related to dbForge Studio 2019 for MySQL. I believe it's creating instanced calling in the IDE that can throw off the LAST_INSERT_ID() in cascaded calls. Once I was able to track down and resolve an error that was returning a bad index (yet had no bearing on a completely un-associated INSERT) everything went back to normal. So it seems this issue was caused by the IDE. Took about 3 hours to figure out because the actual debugger built into dbForge was part of the issue. *sigh*